# Python Error | Basic

Tags: python, syntax

i tried to run this code:

```
cd
sudo apt-get -y install firefox
cd
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar xzf geckodriver-v0.25.0-linux64.tar.gz
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver
```

but i get the following error:

```
>>> cd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined
>>> sudo apt-get -y install firefox
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo apt-get -y install firefox
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> cd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined
>>> wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> tar xzf geckodriver-v0.25.0-linux64.tar.gz
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    tar xzf geckodriver-v0.25.0-linux64.tar.gz
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sudo mv geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo mv geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Every command in your code should be run from bash, not python.

Comment: hmmm. Thanks @ajgringo619 .

Comment: @ajgringo619 that should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if you're running the commands with a Python interpreter. The commands that you show are to be run by a shell, like `bash` etc., in a terminal. It is not Python code.

I can't say anything about the validity of the code apart from that the second `cd` won't do anything and can be deleted, and that the filename used with the `tar` command would need to be modified to match the file downloaded with `wget` (`geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz`).